# When were infinite probability spaces first rigorously dealt with?

Tags: math-history

In other words, when was the transition from exclusive focus on Classical Probability Theory effected? I’m interested in correlating this (approximate) date with something else I am working on, and it would be interesting to know in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by classical probability theory. Are you referring to Kolmogorov axiomatization ? Anyway, before Kolmogorov people already dealt with infinity probability spaces. Take for instance Buffon and geometric probability.

Comment: I have not studied a lot of mathematical history, but Kolmogorov did lots of probability and quite some important work.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you draw the line for infinite probability spaces? Do you consider distributions on $\mathbb{R}$? Would you include random walks? (Which are a kind of infinity that is implicit when you study random variables with finitely many values, in order to formulate the laws of large numbers.) Do you draw the line at Brownian motion? Or is anything other than a finite set with probability distribution "infinite"?

Comment: Most likely the line should be drawn at finite or countably infinite sample spaces (where probability mass functions are fine)  versus uncountably infinite sample spaces.

Comment: A good writeup about Laplace and Kolmogorov on these topics is here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#KolProCal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borel, É. (1909). "Les probabilités dénombrables et leurs applications arithmétiques", *Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo* **27**, 1055-1079

is usually credited for the introduction of $\sigma$-additivity and for the construction of random variables as measurable functions.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I've up-voted and accepted.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks. Have done so now.